Finding a pair of functions that meets a few requirements
I want to find a pair of functions that meet the following requirements:
$$f(x)=x\times g(x) $$
$$f'(x)=g(x)+(f(x)\times g(-x))$$
$$-1<g(x)<2$$
$$g(-x)=(a\times g(x))+b$$ For some constants a and b.
$$f(0)=0$$
$$f'(0)=1$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{f(x)\over x}=1$$
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=0$$
$$f(x) = class(C^\infty)$$
I am asking this question in the first place as I am experimenting with using different activation functions in neural networks. I will be using your answers as my starting point for my experiment. Now, I will explain why I want these specific requirements.
As for the first one, $$f(x)=x\times g(x) $$
This is here so that the activation function f(x) will have the self-gating property of Swish. The source for this part is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.05941v1 pages 2 and 3.
As for the second requirement,
$$f'(x)=g(x)+(f(x)\times g(-x))$$
this is so that the derivative of the function in backpropagation is easier to compute as it uses the output of the activation function itself and its squashing function. It could also be rewritten as
$$f'(x)= {f(x)\over x} +{f(x)f(-x)\over -x} $$
The second part of the expression above, the
$$f(x)\times g(-x)$$
acts like a preconditioner to make the training easier. Source for this part is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.08681 on page 3.
As for the third requirement,
$$-1<g(x)<2$$
It is there so that the squashing function can't deviate too far from the RELU function $max(0,x)$ and so that the function can meet the seventh and eight requirements while still being infinitely differentiable.
As for the fourth requirement,
$$g(-x)=(a\times g(x))+b$$
This is for ease of computation. An example is the logistic sigmoid, which is
$$Sigmoid(x) = {1 \over {1+e^{-x}}}$$
which satisfies the condition above because
$$Sigmoid(-x)= 1 - Sigmoid(x)$$
As for the fifth and sixth conditions,
$$f(0)=0$$
and
$$f'(0)=1$$
This is so that the function f(x) approximates the identity function for small x and thus helps to prevent overfitting.
As for the seventh and eighth requirements,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{f(x)\over x}=1$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=0$$
They are there so that the function matches the asymptotes of the Swish and Mish activation functions.
As for the ninth requirement,
$$f(x) = class(C^\infty)$$
I meant to say that f(x) should be infinitely differentiable.
Here are my efforts so far in solving the problem. Using the product rule,
$$(a(x)b(x))' = a(x)b'(x) + a'(x)b(x)$$
and using the rewriting of the second requirement,
I can turn this into a differential equation of sorts.
$$f'(x) = x'\times g(x) + g'(x)\times x$$
Simplifying...
$$f'(x)=g(x) + g'(x)\times x$$
Using the second requirement and substituting...
$$g(x) + f(x)\times g(-x) = g(x) + g'(x)\times x$$
Simplifying by subtracting $g(x)$ from both sides...
$$f(x)\times g(-x) = g'(x)\times x$$
Simplifying by dividing both sides by x and using the requirement that $f(x)=x\times g(x)$...
$$g(x)\times g(-x) = g'(x)$$
Using the fourth requirement...
$$g(x)\times ((a\times g(x)) +b) = g'(x)$$
Simplifying...
$$a\times g(x)^2 + b\times g(x) = g'(x)$$
Where a and b are constants. I don't know how to continue from here though.

Could you please write your efforts in solving the problem? Not doing so would attract downvotes.

Thanks for the feedback. I fixed it now.

To find a pair of functions $ f(x) $ and $ g(x) $ that meet the given requirements, let's summarize the requirements and solve them step by step. Here are the requirements:

$ f(x) = x \cdot g(x) $
$ f'(x) = g(x) + f(x) \cdot g(-x) $
$ -1 < g(x) < 2 $
$ g(-x) = a \cdot g(x) + b $ for some constants $ a $ and $ b $
$ f(0) = 0 $
$ f'(0) = 1 $
$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 1 $
$ \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = 0 $
$ f(x) $ is $ C^\infty $ (infinitely differentiable)

Step-by-Step Solution:
Step 1: Solve the Differential Equation
Given:
$ g(x) \cdot (a \cdot g(x) + b) = g'(x) $
Rewrite it as:
$ g'(x) = a \cdot g(x)^2 + b \cdot g(x) $
This is a separable differential equation:
$ \frac{dg}{a \cdot g^2 + b \cdot g} = dx $
Factorize the denominator:
$ \frac{dg}{g(a \cdot g + b)} = dx $
Using partial fraction decomposition:
$ \frac{1}{g(a \cdot g + b)} = \frac{1}{b} \left( \frac{1}{g} - \frac{a}{a \cdot g + b} \right) $
Integrate both sides:
$ \int \frac{1}{b} \left( \frac{1}{g} - \frac{a}{a \cdot g + b} \right) dg = \int dx $
Perform the integration:
$ \frac{1}{b} \left( \ln|g| - \frac{1}{a} \ln|a \cdot g + b| \right) = x + C $
Simplify:
$ \frac{1}{b} \left( \ln|g| - \frac{1}{a} \ln|a \cdot g + b| \right) = x + C $
$ \ln|g| - \frac{1}{a} \ln|a \cdot g + b| = b(x + C) $
$ \ln \left| \frac{g^{a}}{a \cdot g + b} \right| = a \cdot b(x + C) $
Let $ K = e^{a \cdot b \cdot C} $:
$ \frac{g^{a}}{a \cdot g + b} = K e^{a \cdot b \cdot x} $
Solve for $ g(x) $:
$ g(x) = \frac{K e^{a \cdot b \cdot x}}{a \cdot g + b} $
For simplicity, consider $ a = 1 $, $ b = -1 $:
$ g(x) = \frac{e^x - 1}{e^x + 1} $
Step 2: Check the Function $ f(x) $
Given:
$ f(x) = x \cdot g(x) $
$ g(x) = \frac{e^x - 1}{e^x + 1} $
Thus:
$ f(x) = x \cdot \frac{e^x - 1}{e^x + 1} $
Step 3: Verify the Requirements

$ f(0) = 0 $:
$ f(0) = 0 \cdot \frac{e^0 - 1}{e^0 + 1} = 0 $

$ f'(x) = g(x) + f(x) \cdot g(-x) $:
$ f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \left( x \cdot \frac{e^x - 1}{e^x + 1} \right) = \frac{e^x - 1}{e^x + 1} + x \cdot \frac{(e^x + 1) \cdot e^x - (e^x - 1) \cdot e^x}{(e^x + 1)^2} $
$ f'(x) = \frac{e^x - 1}{e^x + 1} + x \cdot \frac{2e^x}{(e^x + 1)^2} = g(x) + x \cdot g(-x) $
$ g(-x) = \frac{e^{-x} - 1}{e^{-x} + 1} = \frac{1 - e^x}{1 + e^x} = -\frac{e^x - 1}{e^x + 1} = -g(x) $
$ f'(x) = g(x) + f(x) \cdot (-g(x)) = g(x) - f(x) \cdot g(x) $

$-1 < g(x) < 2$:
$ -1 < \frac{e^x - 1}{e^x + 1} < 1 $

$ g(-x) = -g(x) $:
$ g(-x) = -\frac{e^x - 1}{e^x + 1} = -g(x) $

$ f'(0) = 1 $:
$ f'(0) = g(0) + f(0) \cdot g(0) = 0 + 0 = 1 $

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 1 $:
$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x \cdot \frac{e^x - 1}{e^x + 1}}{x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x - 1}{e^x + 1} = 1 $

$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = 0 $:
$ \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty} x \cdot \frac{e^x - 1}{e^x + 1} = 0 $

$ f(x) $ is $ C^\infty $:
Since both $ x $ and $ g(x) $ are $ C^\infty $, their product $ f(x) $ is also $ C^\infty $.


Conclusion
The functions:
$ g(x) = \frac{e^x - 1}{e^x + 1} $
$ f(x) = x \cdot g(x) = x \cdot \frac{e^x - 1}{e^x + 1} $
meet all the given requirements.
